# Convert JavaScript ternary operator to if than else statement

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm trying to convert the following ternary operator representation to an if-then else statement:

```
return 0 === r.length ? t ? O.toInvalid : null : o(r) ? null : O.toInvalid
```

Could you please help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this statement.

```
if (0 === r.length) {
    if (t) {
        return O.toInvalid;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
} else {
    if (o(r)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return O.toInvalid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if else condition I optimize for you

```
    if ( (!r.length && t) || (r.length && !o(r) ) ) {
        return O.toInvalid;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```